# Filtering and array by a specific property

Tags: javascript, filter

Hello I have the following JavaScript array of objects:

```
  runners = [
      { id: 1, first_name: "Charmain", last_name: "Seiler", email: "cseiler0@wired.com", shirt_size: "2XL", company_name: "Divanoodle", donation: 75 },
      { id: 2, first_name: "Whitaker", last_name: "Ierland", email: "wierland1@angelfire.com", shirt_size: "2XL", company_name: "Wordtune", donation: 148 },
      { id: 3, first_name: "Julieta", last_name: "McCloid", email: "jmccloid2@yahoo.com", shirt_size: "S", company_name: "Riffpedia", donation: 171 },
      { id: 4, first_name: "Martynne", last_name: "Paye", email: "mpaye3@sciencedaily.com", shirt_size: "XL", company_name: "Wordware", donation: 288 },
      { id: 5, first_name: "Gussy", last_name: "Raraty", email: "graraty4@ucoz.ru", shirt_size: "L", company_name: "Oozz", donation: 291 },
  ];
```

I am trying to solve the following challenge and I really don't know what I am doing wrong.
   If anyone could help, this is what I managed to write, I know is not correct, but I don't know why.

```
 /**
     * ### Challenge `getRunnersByTShirtSize`
     * 
     * @instructions
     * The event director needs a way to find the runners that need
     * a specific t-shirt size, so they can place the orders easily.
     * Implement this function using filter().
     * 
     * @param runners array of runners like the one inside the /data/runners.js file.
     * @param tShirtSize string (possible values are "S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL").
     * @returns an array containing only the runners that use the given `tShirtSize`.
     * The runners in the array appear in the same order they appear in the `runners` array.
    */
    function getRunnersByTShirtSize(runners, tShirtSize) {
      /* CODE HERE */
      const newSize =  runners.filter((size) => {
        return runners.size == tShirtSize;  
      });
      return newSize;
    }
```

Comment: What's the key in the object that relates to the `tShirtSize`?  :)

Comment: `size` is not `shirt_size`.

Comment: @Taplar the key related to  `tShirtSize` is `shirt_size`

Comment: So why are you comparing the `tShirtSize` against the size of the array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be `runner.shirt_size` instead of `runners.size`
and your should refernce the item passed in your function `filter((runner)`

```
function getRunnersByTShirtSize(runners, tShirtSize) {
      /* CODE HERE */
      const newSize =  runners.filter((runner) => {
        return runner.shirt_size == tShirtSize;   //<===== not runners.size but instead shirt_size
      });
      return newSize;
    }
```

you can also get rid of the extra variable like this:

```
function getRunnersByTShirtSize(runners, tShirtSize) {
     return runners.filter(runners=> runners.shirt_size == tShirtSize);
 }
```

Comment: So it's a typo.

Comment: check my updated answer, you shouldn't reference `runners` inside your `filter()`